# CCAction blocks does not works in cocos2d v3?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

```
 CCActionCallBlock *call=[CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^
                             {
                                 NSLog(@"***********done");

                             }];
    [self runAction:call];
```

Is not working if i put it in another node, and add this node to my main scene .
It only works in my main scene, and not in any other layer added to that scene .

why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it and it works for me, have you called [super onEnter] on your scene?

If that does not work please a bit more code please.

Comment: yes, it doesn't works in another node. so if i add some other node to my main scene, any sort of action in that other node(layer) is not working.

Comment: does your parent node call [super onEnter] if onEnter is overridden? Can you paste some code please?

Comment: yes! that solve it! calling [super onenter] on the child ! why is that ??

Comment: From the cocos2d source code in CCNode.h ->  If you override onEnter, you shall call [super onEnter].

I've submitted a pull request setting a warning for this case, so hopefully that should warn you about these cases. If you don't want to wait for the next release you can make this changes for now:
[https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/pull/665/files](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/pull/665/files)